# Cómo obtener el selector CSS?

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selectores

Soy nuevo usando selectores CSS y no puedo llegar a obtener el contenido de los elementos de la lista

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

String selector = "#formContent > div > div:nth-child(3) > div.field- 
      select.form-field-wrapper.field-wrapper > div > div.selectize- 
      input.items.has-options.ga_select_originAccount.full.has-items";
      selector.click();
```

Al ejecutar el código sólo le hace click al Combo, por favor agradecería, cómo formar el selector CSS para leer los textos de las clases "title" y "description" de cada uno de los elementos de la lista: Adjunto imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola te dejo 2 links que te puden ser muy utiles para esas tareas https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp
y
https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/attribute-selectors/
a

Answer (score 1):

Para los elementos con clase “title”:

```
.selectize-dropdown span.title
```

Para los elementos con clase “description”:

```
.selectize-dropdown span.description
```

Pero tendrías que recorrer lo que te devuelva ya que será más de un resultado, o bien, acceder al índice del arreglo que te devuelva.